# How to build openembedded packages

Tags: shell, embedded, openembedded, petalinux

I have my petalinux user package with non-commercial license. And i am trying to add the lines `LICENSE_WHITELIST = "non-commercial"`at the end of local.conf file but it is not compiling my package library as i understood that i need to specify the following `URL: git://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core.git`to my local.conf file as it is trying to fetch from `URL ftp://ftp.netperf.org/netperf/archive/netperf-2.6.0.tar.bz2` which is not the right one. How can I do changes to the following file by adding it to whitlist license and with specifying URL.

```
MACHINE ??= "qemuzynq"
DISTRO ?= "petalinux"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
XILINX_VER_MAIN = "2017.1"
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL ?= "https://www.author.xilinx.com/sswreleases/rel-v2017.1/downloads"
INHERIT += "own-mirrors"
INHERIT += "rm_work"

DL_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/downloads"
INHERIT += "uninative"
UNINATIVE_CHECKSUM[x86_64] = "406f783daa6f3923283b3f6ec514cb0470c3a3ea12cb12d5f4bfaec51b2b4dd3"

CONF_VERSION = "1"

INHERIT_remove = "buildhistory icecc"
CONNECTIVITY_CHECK_URIS = ""

SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_SSTATE_EXISTS_CHECK = "none"

SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_TASKSIG_CHECK = "warn"

BB_SETSCENE_ENFORCE_WHITELIST = "%:* *:do_shared_workdir *:do_rm_work *:do_package"





BUILDCFG_HEADER = ""


require conf/locked-sigs.inc
require conf/unlocked-sigs.inc

# Extra settings from environment:
MACHINE = "zynq-generic"

include conf/plnxtool.conf
include conf/petalinuxbsp.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

First you most likely want to do 'LICENSE_WHITELIST += "non-commercial"' to avoid overwriting the values already in the whitelist.

Next, I am not certain what you are getting at with the various URLs but as to why netperf is not being built is most likely related to the fact that there is no dependency on netperf (by any other packages, packagegroups or images which you are building). First ensure it will build with 'bitbake netperf'. Then ensure you include netperf in your image. There are a few ways to accomplish this last one but one way is to append to local.conf with 'IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "netperf"'.